# Was bedeutet "weiterskippen"?

Tags: vocabulary

I don't know whether this is "weiter + skippen" or "weiters + kippen", although the latter seems somewhat implausible because I've never seen "weiters".

In a forum for fans of Nena, I found this:

> Ich hab neulich mal meine Lieblingslieder auf eine CD gepackt und im Auto gehört. Dann habe ich ein paar Patienten im Auto mitgenommen und denen erklärt, dass in meiner Karre Nena angesagt ist. "Yeah, Nena ist voll cool! Die Hör ich auch gern! Bin voll der Fan!" War dann so die Reaktion. Kurz darauf waren die Kids dann am weiterskippen, weil die kein einziges Lied kannten.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you already suspect, it is *weiter+skippen*, where *skippen* is derived from the English verb *skip*, as in “skip from one track to the next on the CD”. The prefix *weiter-* doesn't add much to the meaning, except possibly a notion of directedness (no random hops).

(As an aside, there actually is a word *weiters*. It is used in Austria instead of *weiterhin*.)